# How to (optimally) fetch a button press?

Tags: programming, button

For my hardware, I need to check if the button was pressed, but I need to do things only once every half a second.

`if (digitalRead(pin) == HIGH)
{
    doStuff();
    delay(500);
}`

The above does not work, because I have to check other things in the main loop as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `millis` function (see [millis](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/)).

Create a variable of type `unsigned long` and check it against the current time, with some offset.

See also the [debouncing](https://www.programmingelectronics.com/tutorial-19-debouncing-a-button-with-arduino-old-version/) example, how to use this function and maybe you want to implement the debouncing too.